# Eliminar JCheckBox y que se recoloquen sin dejar espacios

Tags: java, interfaz

Tengo una aplicacion con asociados de un colegio. Los `JCheckBox` corresponden a los asociados que hay en mi lista. Estos asociados los puedo borrar. Cuando en la lista, tras ir borrando, ya no existe un asociado, su `JCheckBox` correspondiente se borra. Eso lo se hacer. El problema es que por ejemplo cuando se borran los Alumnos, me queda un hueco vacio y no se como hacer para que todo quede bien ajustado, sin esos agujeros. He intentado varias cosas como `pack()`, `validate()` o `revalidate()` pero no se muy bien para que sirven (y no me funcionan).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui os dejo el código cuando elimino

```
private class OcultarCheckBoxesNoPertenecientesLista implements ListSelectionListener{

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
        jCheckBoxAlumnos.setVisible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < listaAsociados.size(); i++) {//alumno
           if(listaAsociados.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals(Alumno.class.getSimpleName())){
               jCheckBoxAlumnos.setVisible(true);
           }
        }

        jCheckBoxPadres.setVisible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < listaAsociados.size(); i++) {//padre
           if(listaAsociados.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals(Padre.class.getSimpleName())){
               jCheckBoxPadres.setVisible(true);
           }
        }

        jCheckBoxPersonalNoDocente.setVisible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < listaAsociados.size(); i++) {//personal no docente
           if(listaAsociados.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals(NoDocente.class.getSimpleName())){
               jCheckBoxPersonalNoDocente.setVisible(true);
           }
        }

        jCheckBoxProfesores.setVisible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < listaAsociados.size(); i++) {//profesor
           if(listaAsociados.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals(Profesor.class.getSimpleName())){
               jCheckBoxProfesores.setVisible(true);
           }
        }

        jCheckBoxAlumnos.revalidate();
        jCheckBoxPadres.revalidate();
        jCheckBoxPersonalNoDocente.revalidate();
        jCheckBoxProfesores.revalidate();
        jCheckBoxTodos.revalidate();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Swing* dispone de la clase `BoxLayout` la cual es bastante similar a `FlowLayout` de *AWT*. La diferencia es que con `FlowLayout` los componentes se van alineando horizontalmente mientras que con el `BoxLayout` se pueden acomodar tanto horizontal como verticalmente y ademas, para este caso en particular, al ocultar o hacer visible un componente el re-organizado es automático, no es necesario usar un `revalidate()` o `repaint()` de manera explicita.

Suponiendo que los `JCheckBox` están en un contenedor `miContenedor` bastaría con algo así:

`miContenedor.setLayout(new BoxLayout(miContenedor,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

`Y_AXIS` especifica un orden vertical, es decir, acomodar de arriba hacia abajo cada elemento.

Por supuesto en el apartado de `BoxLayout` de la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) está la información con mas detalle y acerca de [cómo usar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) el *layout*.

Comment: Efectivamente, esa una muy buena solución. Estoy aprendiendo y desconocía esto de los Layouts. Muchas gracias